# Dynamic tab navigation system using Angular 2

Tags: html, typescript, angular, components

I want to create a dynamic tabs navigation system using Angular 2.

Basically I want to first display a single tab that contains a single component, containing clickable objects (like links, buttons...).

I would like that a click on one of those links adds a new tab, and that a click on each tab (the initial one and the newly created tab) displays a corresponding component in display zone (router-outlet) below.

This is what I've tried so far:

app.component.ts (Root component and "tabs container):

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { TabComponent } from './tab/tab.component';
import { FirstComponent } from './test/first.component';
import { SecondComponent } from './test/second.component';
import { ThirdComponent } from './test/third.component';
import { ROUTER_DIRECTIVES } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app/app.component.html',
  directives: [TabComponent, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, FirstComponent, SecondComponent, ThirdComponent],
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit{ 

 tabList: any[];

 constructor() {}

 ngOnInit() {
  this.tabList = [
   {
    name: 'link 1',
    link: "/comp1"
   },
   {
    name: 'link 2',
    link: "/comp2"
   },
   {
    name: 'link 3',
    link: "/comp3"
   }
  ]  
 }
}
```

app.component.html:

```html
<h1>Tabs container</h1>
<div>
 <nav>
  <tab *ngFor="let tab of tabList" [name]="tab.name" [link]="tab.link"></tab>
 </nav>    
</div>
<div>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

Each tab is represented by a tab.component.ts:

```js
import { ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Component, OnInit, Input  } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
 selector: 'tab',
 templateUrl: './app/tab/tab.component.html',
   directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
})

export class TabComponent implements OnInit {
 @Input() name: string;
 @Input() link: string;
 @Input() param: string;
 targetArray: Array<any>;

 constructor(private router: Router) {}

 ngOnInit() {
  
 }

 
}
```

which template is tab.component.html:

```html
<a [routerLink]='link'>{{name}}</a>
```

Here is the app.routes.ts file:

```js
import { provideRouter, RouterConfig } from '@angular/router';
import { TabComponent } from './tab/tab.component';
import { FirstComponent } from './test/first.component';
import { SecondComponent } from './test/second.component';
import { ThirdComponent } from './test/third.component';

export const routes: RouterConfig = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: TabComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'comp1',
    component: FirstComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'comp2',
    component: SecondComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'comp3',
    component: ThirdComponent
  },
];

export const APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS = [
  provideRouter(routes)
];
```

Here is for example the first.component.ts (SecondComponent and ThirdComponent are similar):

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
 selector: 'first',
 template: `<h1>First</h1>
       <button (click)="addTab()">Display child</button>
            `
})
export class FirstComponent implements OnInit {
 constructor() {}

 ngOnInit() {
  
 }

 addTab(){
 }
}
```

I would like to put the tab creation logic in the addTab() method to basically add an element to the tabList array in app.component.ts and obtain the desired behavior but I don't know how to transfer data from this component to the app.component.ts.

I also open to any different approach and suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

You can inject the **Router** into your component and use the **config** method to configure dynamic links.

```js
router.config([
  { 'path': '/', 'component': IndexComp },
  { 'path': '/user/:id', 'component': UserComp },
]);
```

The documentation for the **Router** service can be found [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router-deprecated/index/Router-class.html).

Comment: Thanks for your answer @toskv, but I'm not sure I understand, do you mean I should replace the tabList array in app.component.ts by the router.config you proposed? I actually want to be able to add a new tab dynamically when a corresponding button/link is clicked in the component currently displayed by the router-outlet and to display a corresponding component in the new tab, in regards of what I've done so fare, I thought I should find a way to add elements to the tabList array from the component displayed in the router-outlet which would add a new tab.

Comment: that's the general ideea. Sadly there doesn't seem to be a way to add a route to the current config, so you have to replace all of them. :(

Comment: Is it possible tha an "outlet"component can communicate with a parent component using a shared service?

Comment: I don't see why not. As long as they share the same service instance.